# Localstorage not working in openlayers geolocation

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

**[HERE](http://purplefront.net/ol-3-demos/find-geo-location/)** is a small demo that I pulled form the openlayers3 examples page, you can see a piece of sample code below:

```
var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
        })
    ],
    target: 'map',
    controls: ol.control.defaults({
        attributionOptions: /** @type {olx.control.AttributionOptions} */ ({
            collapsible: false
        })
    }),
    view: view
});
```

Now I wanted to use localStorage and so I modified the code to be as follows:

```
if(!localStorage.layer) {
    localStorage.layer = new ol.layer.Tile({ source: new ol.source.OSM()  })
}

// creating the map
var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: localStorage.layer ? [ localStorage.layer ] : [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
        })
    ],
    target: 'map',
    controls: ol.control.defaults({
        attributionOptions: /** @type {olx.control.AttributionOptions} */ ({
            collapsible: false
        })
    }),
    view: view
});
```

Now this for some reason doesn't work, now if I do some debugging I get the following

Now if I type the following in the console:

```
new ol.layer.Tile({ source: new ol.source.OSM() })
```

I get

```
G {ca: false, ka: undefined, fb: Kc, pd: G, Ma: null…}
```

But if I do

```
localStorage.layer = new ol.layer.Tile({ source: new ol.source.OSM()  })
```

And then type:

```
localStorage.layer
```

I get

```
"[object Object]"
```

So why is 
`localStorage.layer` not equal to new `ol.layer.Tile({ source: new ol.source.OSM() })`? I believe this is what is causing the map to not load. Of course if I remove the localStorage code, the geolocation map works just fine. So why is `localStorage.layer` not equal to new `ol.layer.Tile({ source: new ol.source.OSM() })`?

Comment: You might want to parse `localStorage.layer` by doing something like `JSON.parse(localStorage.layer)`. That will give you the object. But I'm not optimistic about the comparison, as no two objects are identical.

Comment: @HunanRostomyan naa does't work !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Tile` returns some kind of an Object, while the value of `localStorage.getItem(layerStr)` is a String. To extract the stored object from the string, you can do `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(layerStr))`, where `layerStr = JSON.stringify(layer)`. Here is a very contrived example of storing in and retrieving an object from localStorage:

```
var person = {first: 'Tenali', last: 'Raman'};

localStorage.setItem('person', JSON.stringify(person));

JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('person'));  // => {first: 'Tenali', ...}
```

But even then, unfortunately, you can't get the answer you want, as this demonstrates:

```
var storedTile = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(layer));
var storedTile2 = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(layer));

storedTile == storedTile2;  // => false
storedTile === storedTile2;  // => false; follows from the line above
```

In general, objects are compared by identity, not by value. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-to-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects) out on the equality relation between two javascript objects for the details.

Comment: @TenaliRaman That's because localStorage has a different API for getting/setting variables. Although the code above is for demo only, I'll modify it to reflect the Storage API.

Comment: @TenaliRaman I've extended my answer with an illustration of how you can store simple objects in storage and then retrieve them.

Answer (score 0):

The `localStorage` object can store only string , see the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API).

When you do  `localStorage.layer = new ol.layer.Tile({ source: new ol.source.OSM()  })`  in fact you store `(new ol.layer.Tile({ source: new ol.source.OSM()  })).toString()` so  `localStorage.layer = "[object Object]"` and obviously can't be equal to your layer object.

You simply can't store an object in local storage, only string.